# Tic-Tac-Toe: Sqaure cannot be overridden

Tags: javascript

I'm trying my hand at building a tic-tac-toe game with plain vanilla Javascript, so I'm hoping we can stay in the boundaries of keeping it vanilla.

What I require is the following: If a square is already clicked on/occupied by either and "X" or an "O", that square cannot be overridden and an alert/pop-up appears and says to choose another square.

Thank you for your assistance and time!

Here is the code I have got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <style>
        td {

            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 250px;
            width: 250px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 150pt;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square1" onclick="displayMarker('square1');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square2" onclick="displayMarker('square2');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square3" onclick="displayMarker('square3');"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square4" onclick="displayMarker('square4');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square5" onclick="displayMarker('square5');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square6" onclick="displayMarker('square6');"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="square7" onclick="displayMarker('square7');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square8" onclick="displayMarker('square8');"></td>
            <td align="center" id="square9" onclick="displayMarker('square9');"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        var cp1 = 1;

        function displayMarker(allSquares) {

            if (cp1==1) {
                document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML = "X";
                cp1 = 2;
            }

            else {
                document.getElementById(allSquares).innerHTML = "O";
                cp1 = 1;
            }

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if value (innerHTML) of the square is not empty. Alert and return from the function in that case.

```
function displayMarker(allSquares) {
    var square = document.getElementById(allSquares);
    if (square.innerHTML.trim() != "") {
        return alert("Choose another square");
    }
    // ...
```